# Stream to multiple output devices

Tags: c++, portaudio

I am currently trying to develop a soundboard project in c++ with windows.
I search audio library and find portaudio.

I would like to know if it is possible to play the stream on two different audio outputs? with portaudio? or another lib?

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at http://www.un4seen.com/ (bass lib).

```
// initialize the input device
BASS_WASAPI_Init(indevice, 0, 0, BASS_WASAPI_EVENT, 0.5, 0, InWasapiProc, NULL);
// get its sample format
BASS_WASAPI_INFO wi;
BASS_WASAPI_GetInfo(&wi);
// create a push stream with same sample format to receive the input data
instream = BASS_StreamCreate(wi.freq, wi.chans, BASS_STREAM_DECODE|BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT, STREAMPROC_PUSH, NULL);

for (int n = 0; n < num_outputs; n++) {
    // initialize the n'th output device
    BASS_WASAPI_Init(outdevice[n], 0, 0, BASS_WASAPI_EVENT, 0.1, 0, OutWasapiProc, (void*)n);
    // get its sample format
    BASS_WASAPI_INFO wi;
    BASS_WASAPI_GetInfo(&wi);
    // create a mixer with same format
    mixer[n] = BASS_Mixer_StreamCreate(wi.freq, wi.chans, BASS_STREAM_DECODE|BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT);
    // create a splitter on the input push stream and plug it into the mixer
    DWORD splitter = BASS_Split_StreamCreate(instream, BASS_STREAM_DECODE, NULL);
    BASS_Mixer_StreamAddChannel(mixer[n], splitter, BASS_STREAM_AUTOFREE);
}

// start the input device
BASS_WASAPI_SetDevice(indevice);
BASS_WASAPI_Start();
// start the output devices
for (int n = 0; n < num_outputs; n++) {
    BASS_WASAPI_SetDevice(outdevice[n]);
    BASS_WASAPI_Start();
}

...

DWORD CALLBACK InWasapiProc(void *buffer, DWORD length, void *user)
{
    // pass the data to the push stream
    BASS_StreamPutData(instream, buffer, length);
    return 1;
}

DWORD CALLBACK OutWasapiProc(void *buffer, DWORD length, void *user)
{
    // get data from the output's mixer
    int n = (int)user;
    int got = BASS_ChannelGetData(mixer[n], buffer, length);
    if (got < 0) got = 0;
    return got;
}
```